# How to create object for a class dynamically in java

Tags: java

I had a scenario like this,

```
 String className;

 if(someCondition){

 className="A";

   }
 else{
   className='B'
  }
```

Now i want to do this dynamically

```
 className obj=(className) dbObj;//i am typcasting the db casting to particular class
```

Note:Here A and B classes having same setters and getters but belongs to two different tables in db

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your design a littel bit.

Both the classes `A` and `B` should implement same inteface.

```
interface IAB {
}

class A implements IAB {
}

class B implements IAB {
}
```

Now, change your code as following:

```
IAB className;

if(someCondition) {
    className = (A) dbObj;
}
else {
    className = (B) dbObj;
}
```

OR

```
classname = (someCondition ? A : B) dbObj;
```